# Append options to select with xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to append options to a select I get from a template.

The technique itself works fine, except for the fact that only the last iterated option is actually in the HTML. So I'm not sure if it's actually appending or just over-writing everything in my select template.

```
$select = $this->elementTemplate->query('//select')->item(0);
foreach ($values as $value) {
    //Check to see post data is set, and if it is check if the value is the same. In case it is the option is 'selected'.
    if ($this->postData[$this->properties->get('name')] != "") {
        $selected = ($this->postData[$this->properties->get('name')] == $value) ? 'selected' : '';
    }

    $optionTemplate->setAttribute('value', $value);
    if ($selected == 'selected') {
        $optionTemplate->setAttribute('selected', $selected);
    }
    $optionTemplate->nodeValue = $value;
    $select->appendChild($optionTemplate);
}

//Last but not least re-fetch the div(container of the label and input) and set it
$div = $this->elementTemplate->query('//div')->item(0);
$this->setHTML($this->getInnerHTMLOfElement($div));
```

Comment: I barely know any PHP, but it looks like you are appending the same `$optionTemplate` all the time (the initialization of `$optionTemplate` is not in your snippet here). You might have to create a new object and append this each run in you `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

`$optionTemplate` isn't defined anywhere, so adding this inside the loop should fix it:

`$optionTemplate = $doc->createElement('option');`

(where `$doc` is the parent document)